# Caret: Model Predicts only one Class

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

I'm building a credit default prediction model.
The prediction for all 100 of my test cases is: NonDefault. 
I'm not sure why (bug, error, ...)?

I have my training data and test data in two distinct .csv files.
Both have the same number of columns.  My class output variable (e.g. LoanStatus) is in the last column of the file and was designated as a Factor.  There is a column header for LoanStatus in the test data file but all the values are empty.

```
credit$LoanStatus <- as.factor(credit$LoanStatus)
creditTesting$LoanStatus <- as.factor(creditTesting$LoanStatus)

str(credit)
'data.frame':   8580 obs. of  37 variables:
 $ ListingCategory            : int  1 7 3 1 1 7 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ IncomeRange                : int  3 4 6 4 4 3 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ StatedMonthlyIncome        : num  2583 4326 10500 4167 5667 ...
 $ IncomeVerifiable           : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ DTIwProsperLoan            : num  1.8e-01 2.0e-01 1.7e-01 1.0e+06 1.8e-01 4.4e-01 2.2e-01 2.0e-01 2.0e-01 3.1e-01 ...
 $ EmploymentStatusDescription: Factor w/ 7 levels "Employed","Full-time",..: 1 4 1 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BorrowerState              : Factor w/ 48 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 22 32 5 5 14 28 4 10 10 34 ...
 $ LenderIndicator            : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ GroupIndicator             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ ChannelCode                : int  90000 90000 90000 80000 40000 40000 90000 90000 80000 90000 ...
 $ MonthlyDebt                : int  247 785 1631 817 644 1524 427 817 654 749 ...
 $ CurrentDelinquencies       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ DelinquenciesLast7Years    : int  0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PublicRecordsLast10Years   : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ PublicRecordsLast12Months  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CreditLinesLast7Years      : int  53 30 36 26 7 22 15 20 34 32 ...
 $ InquiriesLast6Months       : int  2 8 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 ...
 $ AmountDelinquent           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 63 0 15 ...
 $ CurrentCreditLines         : int  10 10 18 10 4 11 6 10 7 8 ...
 $ OpenCreditLines            : int  9 10 15 8 3 8 5 7 7 8 ...
 $ BankcardUtilization        : num  0.26 0.69 0.94 0.69 0.81 0.38 0.55 0.24 0.03 0 ...
 $ TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts : int  9 7 12 10 3 5 4 5 4 6 ...
 $ RealEstateBalance          : int  0 0 577745 0 0 0 191296 0 0 126039 ...
 $ RevolvingBalance           : int  5265 9967 94966 50511 37871 22463 19550 2436 1223 3236 ...
 $ RealEstatePayment          : int  0 0 4159 0 0 0 1303 0 0 1279 ...
 $ RevolvingAvailablePercent  : int  78 52 36 45 18 61 44 74 96 76 ...
 $ TotalInquiries             : int  8 11 15 2 0 0 1 7 1 1 ...
 $ TotalTradeItems            : int  53 30 36 26 7 22 15 20 34 32 ...
 $ SatisfactoryAccounts       : int  52 23 36 26 7 19 15 18 34 29 ...
 $ NowDelinquentDerog         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ WasDelinquentDerog         : int  1 7 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 2 ...
 $ OldestTradeOpenDate        : int  5092001 5011977 12011984 4272000 9081993 9122000 6161987 11181999 9191990 4132000 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver30Days    : int  0 6 0 0 0 13 0 2 0 2 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver60Days    : int  0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver90Days    : int  0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IsHomeowner                : logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ LoanStatus                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Default","NonDefault": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...

str(creditTesting)
'data.frame':   101 obs. of  45 variables:
 $ ListingCategory            : int  1 2 6 2 1 1 1 1 2 18 ...
 $ IncomeRange                : int  3 3 4 3 4 3 6 5 3 4 ...
 $ StatedMonthlyIncome        : num  3333 2500 4271 2667 5000 ...
 $ IncomeVerifiable           : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ DTIwProsperLoan            : num  5.9e-01 8.0e-01 3.3e-01 1.0e-01 1.4e-01 2.2e-01 1.4e-01 1.5e-01 1.0e+06 2.2e-01 ...
 $ EmploymentStatusDescription: Factor w/ 5 levels "Employed","Full-time",..: 1 2 1 1 1 4 1 1 5 1 ...
 $ Occupation                 : Factor w/ 34 levels "Accountant/CPA",..: 21 30 2 34 22 22 28 25 25 25 ...
 $ MonthsEmployed             : int  113 176 112 86 19 0 295 100 12 19 ...
 $ BorrowerState              : Factor w/ 32 levels "AL","CA","CO",..: 7 4 13 7 4 7 20 20 20 29 ...
 $ BorrowerCity               : Factor w/ 91 levels "ARLINGTON","ATLANTA",..: 7 32 46 15 62 14 58 61 16 18 ...
 $ BorrowerMetropolitanArea   : Factor w/ 1 level "(Not Implemented)": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LenderIndicator            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GroupIndicator             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ GroupName                  : Factor w/ 3 levels "","1st and BEST for Loans",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ChannelCode                : int  70000 80000 80000 80000 40000 70000 90000 40000 90000 40000 ...
 $ AmountParticipation        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ MonthlyDebt                : int  1450 1622 1329 132 555 353 513 1014 3279 835 ...
 $ CurrentDelinquencies       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DelinquenciesLast7Years    : int  0 0 0 9 21 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PublicRecordsLast10Years   : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PublicRecordsLast12Months  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FirstRecordedCreditLine    : Factor w/ 99 levels "1/12/91 0:00",..: 73 65 67 21 44 6 29 97 20 41 ...
 $ CreditLinesLast7Years      : int  44 39 16 14 24 24 39 26 34 21 ...
 $ InquiriesLast6Months       : int  1 0 0 2 3 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ AmountDelinquent           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CurrentCreditLines         : int  26 15 8 8 7 9 14 16 17 11 ...
 $ OpenCreditLines            : int  25 14 8 7 6 6 10 16 16 10 ...
 $ BankcardUtilization        : num  0.51 0.82 0.96 0.24 0.08 0.62 0.63 0.95 0.92 0.17 ...
 $ TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts : int  26 13 6 6 7 7 10 15 16 8 ...
 $ InstallmentBalance         : int  22471 7373 11312 0 23022 0 0 9096 4322 12224 ...
 $ RealEstateBalance          : int  101872 0 0 187094 0 0 467861 149718 0 169056 ...
 $ RevolvingBalance           : int  41511 44578 19246 2301 1357 10462 38677 33587 114211 12305 ...
 $ RealEstatePayment          : int  743 0 0 1000 0 0 3990 1064 0 1438 ...
 $ RevolvingAvailablePercent  : int  55 18 25 79 92 52 40 11 19 78 ...
 $ TotalInquiries             : int  2 6 2 6 7 2 4 4 0 7 ...
 $ TotalTradeItems            : int  44 39 16 14 24 24 39 26 34 21 ...
 $ SatisfactoryAccounts       : int  44 38 15 13 22 20 39 26 34 20 ...
 $ NowDelinquentDerog         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WasDelinquentDerog         : int  0 1 1 1 2 4 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ OldestTradeOpenDate        : int  7011999 6101990 6171985 11162005 3012000 1081990 11061996 9261994 11011977 2252002 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver30Days    : int  0 1 0 3 1 13 0 0 0 2 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver60Days    : int  0 0 0 2 1 2 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver90Days    : int  0 0 0 9 21 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IsHomeowner                : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ LoanStatus                 : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
summary(credit)
ListingCategory   IncomeRange    StatedMonthlyIncome IncomeVerifiable
 Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :     0      Mode :logical   
 1st Qu.: 1.000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:  3167      FALSE:784       
 Median : 2.000   Median :4.000   Median :  4750      TRUE :7796      
 Mean   : 4.997   Mean   :4.089   Mean   :  5755      NA's :0         
 3rd Qu.: 7.000   3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:  7083                      
 Max.   :20.000   Max.   :7.000   Max.   :250000                      

 DTIwProsperLoan     EmploymentStatusDescription BorrowerState 
 Min.   :      0.0   Employed     :7182          CA     :1056  
 1st Qu.:      0.1   Full-time    : 416          FL     : 608  
 Median :      0.2   Not employed : 122          NY     : 574  
 Mean   :  91609.4   Other        : 475          TX     : 532  
 3rd Qu.:      0.3   Part-time    :   7          IL     : 443  
 Max.   :1000000.0   Retired      :  32          GA     : 343  
                     Self-employed: 346          (Other):5024  
 LenderIndicator   GroupIndicator   ChannelCode     MonthlyDebt     
 Min.   :0.00000   Mode :logical   Min.   :40000   Min.   :    0.0  
 1st Qu.:0.00000   FALSE:8325      1st Qu.:80000   1st Qu.:  364.0  
 Median :0.00000   TRUE :255       Median :80000   Median :  708.0  
 Mean   :0.09196   NA's :0         Mean   :77196   Mean   :  885.5  
 3rd Qu.:0.00000                   3rd Qu.:90000   3rd Qu.: 1205.2  
 Max.   :1.00000                   Max.   :90000   Max.   :30213.0  

 CurrentDelinquencies DelinquenciesLast7Years PublicRecordsLast10Years
 Min.   : 0.0000      Min.   : 0.000          Min.   : 0.0000         
 1st Qu.: 0.0000      1st Qu.: 0.000          1st Qu.: 0.0000         
 Median : 0.0000      Median : 0.000          Median : 0.0000         
 Mean   : 0.4119      Mean   : 4.009          Mean   : 0.2809         
 3rd Qu.: 0.0000      3rd Qu.: 3.000          3rd Qu.: 0.0000         
 Max.   :21.0000      Max.   :99.000          Max.   :11.0000         

 PublicRecordsLast12Months CreditLinesLast7Years InquiriesLast6Months
 Min.   :0.00000           Min.   :  2.0         Min.   : 0.0000     
 1st Qu.:0.00000           1st Qu.: 16.0         1st Qu.: 0.0000     
 Median :0.00000           Median : 24.0         Median : 1.0000     
 Mean   :0.01364           Mean   : 26.1         Mean   : 0.9994     
 3rd Qu.:0.00000           3rd Qu.: 34.0         3rd Qu.: 1.0000     
 Max.   :4.00000           Max.   :115.0         Max.   :15.0000     

 AmountDelinquent CurrentCreditLines OpenCreditLines  BankcardUtilization
 Min.   :     0   Min.   : 0.000     Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :0.0000     
 1st Qu.:     0   1st Qu.: 5.000     1st Qu.: 5.000   1st Qu.:0.2500     
 Median :     0   Median : 9.000     Median : 8.000   Median :0.5400     
 Mean   :  1195   Mean   : 9.345     Mean   : 8.306   Mean   :0.5182     
 3rd Qu.:     0   3rd Qu.:12.000     3rd Qu.:11.000   3rd Qu.:0.7900     
 Max.   :179158   Max.   :54.000     Max.   :42.000   Max.   :2.2300     

 TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts RealEstateBalance RevolvingBalance
 Min.   : 0.000             Min.   :      0   Min.   :     0  
 1st Qu.: 3.000             1st Qu.:      0   1st Qu.:  2799  
 Median : 6.000             Median :  26154   Median :  8784  
 Mean   : 6.441             Mean   : 109306   Mean   : 19555  
 3rd Qu.: 9.000             3rd Qu.: 176542   3rd Qu.: 21110  
 Max.   :44.000             Max.   :1938421   Max.   :695648  

 RealEstatePayment RevolvingAvailablePercent TotalInquiries  TotalTradeItems
 Min.   :    0.0   Min.   :  0.00            Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :  2.0  
 1st Qu.:    0.0   1st Qu.: 29.00            1st Qu.: 2.00   1st Qu.: 16.0  
 Median :  346.5   Median : 52.00            Median : 3.00   Median : 24.0  
 Mean   :  830.5   Mean   : 51.46            Mean   : 3.91   Mean   : 26.1  
 3rd Qu.: 1382.2   3rd Qu.: 75.00            3rd Qu.: 5.00   3rd Qu.: 34.0  
 Max.   :13651.0   Max.   :100.00            Max.   :36.00   Max.   :115.0  

 SatisfactoryAccounts NowDelinquentDerog WasDelinquentDerog OldestTradeOpenDate
 Min.   :  1.00       Min.   : 0.0000    Min.   : 0.000     Min.   : 1011957   
 1st Qu.: 14.00       1st Qu.: 0.0000    1st Qu.: 0.000     1st Qu.: 4101996   
 Median : 21.00       Median : 0.0000    Median : 1.000     Median : 7191993   
 Mean   : 23.34       Mean   : 0.4119    Mean   : 2.343     Mean   : 6934230   
 3rd Qu.: 30.25       3rd Qu.: 0.0000    3rd Qu.: 3.000     3rd Qu.:10011990   
 Max.   :113.00       Max.   :21.0000    Max.   :32.000     Max.   :12312004   

 DelinquenciesOver30Days DelinquenciesOver60Days DelinquenciesOver90Days
 Min.   : 0.000          Min.   : 0.000          Min.   : 0.000         
 1st Qu.: 0.000          1st Qu.: 0.000          1st Qu.: 0.000         
 Median : 1.000          Median : 0.000          Median : 0.000         
 Mean   : 4.332          Mean   : 1.908          Mean   : 4.009         
 3rd Qu.: 5.000          3rd Qu.: 2.000          3rd Qu.: 3.000         
 Max.   :99.000          Max.   :73.000          Max.   :99.000         

 IsHomeowner          LoanStatus  
 Mode :logical   Default   :1518  
 FALSE:4264      NonDefault:7062  
 TRUE :4316                       
 NA's :0                          



In [113]:

summary(creditTesting)
Out[113]:
 ListingCategory   IncomeRange    StatedMonthlyIncome IncomeVerifiable
 Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :    0       Mode :logical   
 1st Qu.: 1.000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.: 3583       FALSE:5         
 Median : 1.000   Median :4.000   Median : 5000       TRUE :96        
 Mean   : 4.277   Mean   :4.119   Mean   : 5696       NA's :0         
 3rd Qu.: 3.000   3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.: 6833                       
 Max.   :20.000   Max.   :7.000   Max.   :37500                       

 DTIwProsperLoan     EmploymentStatusDescription                    Occupation
 Min.   :      0.0   Employed     :86            Other                   :22  
 1st Qu.:      0.1   Full-time    : 4            Professional            :13  
 Median :      0.2   Not employed : 1            Sales - Commission      : 6  
 Mean   :  49510.2   Other        : 7            Computer Programmer     : 5  
 3rd Qu.:      0.3   Self-employed: 3            Accountant/CPA          : 4  
 Max.   :1000000.0                               Administrative Assistant: 4  
                                                 (Other)                 :47  
 MonthsEmployed   BorrowerState     BorrowerCity      BorrowerMetropolitanArea
 Min.   : -1.00   CA     :13    BROOKLYN  : 3    (Not Implemented):101        
 1st Qu.: 26.00   NJ     : 8    LOUISVILLE: 3                                 
 Median : 71.00   IL     : 7    ATLANTA   : 2                                 
 Mean   : 98.47   TX     : 7    CHICAGO   : 2                                 
 3rd Qu.:152.00   FL     : 6    LAKEWOOD  : 2                                 
 Max.   :424.00   NY     : 6    RACINE    : 2                                 
                  (Other):54    (Other)   :87                                 
 LenderIndicator   GroupIndicator                      GroupName 
 Min.   :0.00000   Mode :logical                            :98  
 1st Qu.:0.00000   FALSE:97        1st and BEST for Loans   : 1  
 Median :0.00000   TRUE :4         BORROWERS - LARGEST GROUP: 2  
 Mean   :0.05941   NA's :0                                       
 3rd Qu.:0.00000                                                 
 Max.   :1.00000                                                 

  ChannelCode    AmountParticipation  MonthlyDebt     CurrentDelinquencies
 Min.   :40000   Min.   :0           Min.   :  25.0   Min.   :0.0000      
 1st Qu.:70000   1st Qu.:0           1st Qu.: 474.0   1st Qu.:0.0000      
 Median :80000   Median :0           Median : 814.0   Median :0.0000      
 Mean   :74059   Mean   :0           Mean   : 888.9   Mean   :0.3168      
 3rd Qu.:90000   3rd Qu.:0           3rd Qu.:1189.0   3rd Qu.:0.0000      
 Max.   :90000   Max.   :0           Max.   :5928.0   Max.   :8.0000      

 DelinquenciesLast7Years PublicRecordsLast10Years PublicRecordsLast12Months
 Min.   : 0.000          Min.   :0.0000           Min.   :0                
 1st Qu.: 0.000          1st Qu.:0.0000           1st Qu.:0                
 Median : 0.000          Median :0.0000           Median :0                
 Mean   : 4.139          Mean   :0.3168           Mean   :0                
 3rd Qu.: 3.000          3rd Qu.:0.0000           3rd Qu.:0                
 Max.   :51.000          Max.   :7.0000           Max.   :0                

 FirstRecordedCreditLine CreditLinesLast7Years InquiriesLast6Months
 4/1/95 0:00 : 2         Min.   : 4.00         Min.   :0.0000      
 9/26/94 0:00: 2         1st Qu.:17.00         1st Qu.:0.0000      
 1/12/91 0:00: 1         Median :26.00         Median :1.0000      
 1/13/89 0:00: 1         Mean   :27.08         Mean   :0.9604      
 1/20/98 0:00: 1         3rd Qu.:37.00         3rd Qu.:2.0000      
 1/26/01 0:00: 1         Max.   :67.00         Max.   :5.0000      
 (Other)     :93                                                   
 AmountDelinquent CurrentCreditLines OpenCreditLines  BankcardUtilization
 Min.   :    0    Min.   : 1.000     Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :0.0000     
 1st Qu.:    0    1st Qu.: 6.000     1st Qu.: 5.000   1st Qu.:0.3400     
 Median :    0    Median : 9.000     Median : 8.000   Median :0.6000     
 Mean   : 1153    Mean   : 9.782     Mean   : 8.802   Mean   :0.5679     
 3rd Qu.:    0    3rd Qu.:14.000     3rd Qu.:12.000   3rd Qu.:0.8000     
 Max.   :56288    Max.   :26.000     Max.   :25.000   Max.   :1.0000     

 TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts InstallmentBalance RealEstateBalance
 Min.   : 0.000             Min.   :     0     Min.   :      0  
 1st Qu.: 4.000             1st Qu.:  2657     1st Qu.:      0  
 Median : 6.000             Median : 13109     Median :      0  
 Mean   : 7.109             Mean   : 26038     Mean   : 101924  
 3rd Qu.:10.000             3rd Qu.: 32549     3rd Qu.: 149718  
 Max.   :26.000             Max.   :220085     Max.   :1571558  
                            NA's   :3                           
 RevolvingBalance RealEstatePayment RevolvingAvailablePercent TotalInquiries  
 Min.   :     0   Min.   :   0.0    Min.   :  0.00            Min.   : 0.000  
 1st Qu.:  4422   1st Qu.:   0.0    1st Qu.: 32.00            1st Qu.: 2.000  
 Median :  8886   Median :   0.0    Median : 50.00            Median : 4.000  
 Mean   : 24627   Mean   : 757.8    Mean   : 49.18            Mean   : 3.772  
 3rd Qu.: 21189   3rd Qu.:1217.0    3rd Qu.: 68.00            3rd Qu.: 5.000  
 Max.   :795296   Max.   :7830.0    Max.   :100.00            Max.   :13.000  

 TotalTradeItems SatisfactoryAccounts NowDelinquentDerog WasDelinquentDerog
 Min.   : 4.00   Min.   : 2.00        Min.   :0.0000     Min.   : 0.000    
 1st Qu.:17.00   1st Qu.:15.00        1st Qu.:0.0000     1st Qu.: 0.000    
 Median :26.00   Median :22.00        Median :0.0000     Median : 1.000    
 Mean   :27.08   Mean   :24.35        Mean   :0.3168     Mean   : 2.416    
 3rd Qu.:37.00   3rd Qu.:34.00        3rd Qu.:0.0000     3rd Qu.: 4.000    
 Max.   :67.00   Max.   :67.00        Max.   :8.0000     Max.   :17.000    

 OldestTradeOpenDate DelinquenciesOver30Days DelinquenciesOver60Days
 Min.   : 1081990    Min.   : 0.000          Min.   : 0.000         
 1st Qu.: 4131991    1st Qu.: 0.000          1st Qu.: 0.000         
 Median : 8032006    Median : 1.000          Median : 0.000         
 Mean   : 7123082    Mean   : 4.614          Mean   : 2.089         
 3rd Qu.:10012009    3rd Qu.: 6.000          3rd Qu.: 2.000         
 Max.   :12301997    Max.   :41.000          Max.   :20.000         

 DelinquenciesOver90Days IsHomeowner     LoanStatus
 Min.   : 0.000          Mode :logical   NA's:101  
 1st Qu.: 0.000          FALSE:59                  
 Median : 0.000          TRUE :42                  
 Mean   : 4.139          NA's :0                   
 3rd Qu.: 3.000                                    
 Max.   :51.000                                    

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3, classProbs = TRUE,  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

multinomFit <- train(LoanStatus~., credit, method = "multinom", family=binomial, metric = "ROC",
    preProcess=c("center", "scale", "pca"), 
    trControl = ctrl)

Penalized Multinomial Regression 

8580 samples
  36 predictor
   2 classes: 'Default', 'NonDefault' 

Pre-processing: centered, scaled, principal component signal extraction 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 7721, 7722, 7722, 7722, 7722, 7723, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  decay  ROC        Sens        Spec       ROC SD      Sens SD     Spec SD    
  0e+00  0.6475924  0.01909783  0.9945719  0.02439430  0.01070060  0.002929591
  1e-04  0.6475921  0.01909783  0.9945719  0.02439472  0.01070060  0.002929591
  1e-01  0.6475930  0.01887853  0.9945719  0.02440801  0.01061464  0.002929591

ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was decay = 0.1.
```

Call:
multinom(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = dat, decay = param$decay, 
    family = ..1)

```
Coefficients:
                   Values  Std. Err.
(Intercept)  1.661559e+00 0.03135811
PC1         -8.412986e-02 0.01222495
PC2          4.553628e-02 0.01278523
PC3          1.219468e-01 0.01555913
PC4          6.770858e-02 0.01996412
PC5         -3.103824e-02 0.01907472
PC6          3.550245e-02 0.02133001
PC7          1.443212e-01 0.02396368
PC8          2.074222e-01 0.02760976
PC9         -1.651602e-01 0.02448699
PC10        -1.339219e-01 0.02481627
PC11        -8.404567e-02 0.02479423
PC12         9.089093e-02 0.02924268
PC13        -4.247345e-02 0.02753968
PC14         2.509833e-02 0.02665515
PC15         4.533390e-02 0.02832468
PC16        -3.765632e-02 0.02759775
PC17         1.906671e-02 0.02859806
PC18        -2.857844e-02 0.02777393
PC19        -2.601204e-02 0.02821992
PC20         4.960850e-02 0.02824554
PC21         7.618470e-02 0.02794719
PC22         1.577422e-02 0.02808431
PC23        -2.763435e-02 0.02796787
PC24        -2.454515e-03 0.02902528
PC25         8.217990e-03 0.02808979
PC26         3.184139e-02 0.02901644
PC27         3.955461e-02 0.02916539
PC28         1.260333e-01 0.02984005
PC29        -3.960489e-02 0.02949268
PC30        -8.586754e-02 0.02889836
PC31        -2.481118e-02 0.02795710
PC32        -4.558708e-03 0.02976663
PC33         1.298065e-02 0.02745320
PC34         2.451963e-02 0.02824458
PC35         1.248370e-02 0.02895790
PC36        -1.463200e-02 0.02854997
PC37        -1.196070e-02 0.02897936
PC38         5.596941e-02 0.02902472
PC39        -5.391409e-02 0.02956513
PC40         2.108806e-02 0.02779666
PC41        -9.459884e-03 0.02849543
PC42        -6.300733e-02 0.02830865
PC43         2.135377e-02 0.02996247
PC44         6.512672e-03 0.03040486
PC45        -4.486076e-02 0.02837301
PC46        -2.150908e-02 0.03071156
PC47         2.169651e-03 0.02968346
PC48         5.521734e-02 0.03204429
PC49         3.248101e-02 0.03005834
PC50         2.464231e-02 0.03058966
PC51         3.244047e-02 0.02980442
PC52         9.181668e-05 0.02957302
PC53        -5.255398e-02 0.02916945
PC54         2.471085e-02 0.02861254
PC55         1.299871e-01 0.02982951
PC56         4.561386e-03 0.02848702
PC57        -1.546641e-02 0.02797762
PC58         1.001523e-01 0.03000506
PC59         5.561718e-02 0.03021967
PC60        -4.221097e-02 0.03084724
PC61        -3.205970e-02 0.02969792
PC62        -7.822227e-02 0.03237215
PC63        -6.974787e-02 0.03219820
PC64        -8.391386e-02 0.03218637
PC65        -5.468543e-02 0.03329968
PC66         1.149728e-01 0.03465573
PC67         7.122453e-02 0.03717676
PC68        -7.438698e-02 0.03355053

Residual Deviance: 7540.3 
AIC: 7678.3 

multinomClasses <- predict(multinomFit, newdata = creditTesting)

multinomClasses
NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault Default NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault NonDefault

multinomProbs <- predict(multinomFit, newdata = creditTesting, type = "prob")

multinomProbs
Default NonDefault
1   0.1696353   0.8303647
2   0.1294708   0.8705292
3   0.2195003   0.7804997
4   0.2239879   0.7760121
5   0.1320599   0.8679401
6   0.2361062   0.7638938
7   0.08251747  0.9174825
8   0.1157858   0.8842142
9   0.2883426   0.7116574
10  0.1005039   0.8994961
11  0.09416405  0.905836
12  0.2575161   0.7424839
13  0.5283096   0.4716904
14  0.006361443 0.9936386
15  0.1884999   0.8115001
16  0.1195356   0.8804644
17  0.1997128   0.8002872
18  0.2019061   0.7980939
19  0.2959732   0.7040268
20  0.1662932   0.8337068
21  0.06248543  0.9375146
22  0.08954305  0.9104569
23  0.1669996   0.8330004
24  0.1366132   0.8633868
25  0.09438881  0.9056112
26  0.07180876  0.9281912
27  0.1387811   0.8612189
28  0.3140691   0.6859309
29  0.2012253   0.7987747
30  0.3330198   0.6669802
31  0.1883894   0.8116106
32  0.1444536   0.8555464
33  0.08972971  0.9102703
34  0.09828264  0.9017174
35  0.1547096   0.8452904
36  0.06803248  0.9319675
37  0.09852268  0.9014773
38  0.07810421  0.9218958
39  0.1635697   0.8364303
40  0.2745873   0.7254127
41  0.2124576   0.7875424
42  0.1263433   0.8736567
43  0.1460307   0.8539693
44  0.212215    0.787785
45  0.156162    0.843838
46  0.261491    0.738509
47  0.1256826   0.8743174
48  0.2127443   0.7872557
49  0.1219385   0.8780615
50  0.1885034   0.8114966
51  0.1520502   0.8479498
52  0.2068344   0.7931656
53  0.1229164   0.8770836
54  0.1614266   0.8385734
55  0.1464662   0.8535338
56  0.1398765   0.8601235
57  0.3510801   0.6489199
58  0.1208267   0.8791733
59  0.08798058  0.9120194
60  0.2338337   0.7661663
```

...
    100 0.08459862  0.9154014
    101 0.2787546   0.7212454
    In [119]:

```
levels(multinomClasses)
Out[119]:
'Default' 'NonDefault'
```

Comment: 1-when you say `There is a column header for LoanStatus in the test data file but all the values are empty`, this means you do not know the actual response for the test dataset, and your goal is to predict it without the ability to evaluate your model on the provided test dataset. So, there is no point of  doing `creditTesting$LoanStatus <- as.factor(creditTesting$LoanStatus)`  and you can not use it in the `confusionMatrix` (that is why you got an error when you did last time).

Comment: 2- In this case, you need to split the data you have with `LoanStatus` to train and test dataset. As I said before, use caret's stratified sampling.

Comment: 3- Credit assessment is a typical case of imbalanced dataset, where the number of `Default` is much smaller than `NonDefault`. Try doing `table(credit$LoanStatus)`. There are several ways to deal with this.

Comment: 4 - The fact that your model is predicting all test cases as `NonDefault` may not be a problem (they may be all `NonDefault` or the `Default` is extremely low). The only way to evaluate your model is to test it on a data that you know its actual responses.

Comment: I think we need to see all the code (and have a reproducible example) to help in any meaningful way. Certainly if you have a severe class imbalance, I wouldn't be surprised if your model predicts everything to be the majority class.

Comment: Many of my attributes were categorical.  Would I be better off using Multiple Correspondence Analysis instead of PCA?  http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/multiple-correspondence-analysis.html